# Non-nonsensical optimization in C

Tags: c, gcc

When using optimizations O2 and above with gcc I get unexpected output with the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f ( int *a, float *b ) {
    *a = 1;
    *b = 0;
    printf ( "%d ", *a );
    return *a;
}

int main ( ) {
    int i = 0;

    printf ( "%d\n", f ( &i, &i ) );
}
```

This code normally should print "0 0" but instead with -O2 is prints "1 0". Then if I remove the printf in the function f it just prints 1. That is the same printf statement having its output changed by a printline.

Why does this happen?

Also I am aware I should never be doing this, I just want to know why it's happening.

Comment: Well, this is called "undefined behavior". You are breaking strict-aliasing rule here.

Comment: If you have undefined behavior, the compiler can do whatever it wants. So especially when you're compiling with a high optimization level, it is going to leverage that fact and take shortcuts. There's no point in trying to find out why UB manifests the way it does.

Comment: it hapenned because the UB gods were happy and made you lucky. had they been unhappy, everything would work as you expected.... unless your boss was watching!

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The OP asked why it happened. They did not ask what rule in the C standard makes it happen. They did not ask how the C standard applies. They effectively acknowledged this behavior is not defined by the C standard. But there is an answer to their question. The C standard is not the only thing that affects compiler behavior, and compiler behavior can be analyzed and understood beyond what the C standard requires.

Comment: Thank you. I know this is undefined behavior, I was just looking for why it might be handled this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With both [`-O0`](https://godbolt.org/z/KRFM7m) and [`-O2`](https://godbolt.org/z/EOdpMC), GCC 9.2 generates code that performs `*a = 1;` first  and `*b = 0;` second.

In the unoptimized case, it then loads `*a` from memory to pass it to `printf` and to return it. Since `i` was set to 0 by `*b = 0;`, loading it as `*a` produces 0, and that is what is printed and what is returned.

In the optimized case, the compiler assumes `*a` and `*b` are different objects and, therefore, that the `*a = 1;` has set the value of `*a` to 1, and that the `*b = 0;` did not change it. Consequently, when passing `*a` to `printf`, it passes 1 without loading it from memory. (The 1 is hard-coded as an immediate operand in an instruction.)